# HTML form semantics

Tags: html, semantics

This is a pure semantic question.

On my website, I have a guestbook in which you can post a comment and edit it. For posting or editing your comment, there are two very similar forms. Javascript will choose whether the form for posting or the form for editing will be visible (since all happens asynchronously). These are the two forms:

```
<form class="comment">
   <h1>Comment</h1>
   <label>Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="50" maxlength="60" /></label>
   <label class="title_error error">Required.</label>
   <label>Author: <input type="text" name="author_name" size="25" maxlength="35" /></label>
   <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="8" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
   <label class="content_error error">Required.</label>
   <input type="submit" value="Comment" onclick="return addComment($(this).parent());" />
</form>

<form class="edit">
   <h1>Edit your comment</h1>
   <label>Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="50" maxlength="60" /></label>
   <label class="title_error error">Required.</label>
   <label>Author: <input type="text" name="author_name" size="25" maxlength="35" /></label>
   <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="8" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
   <label class="content_error error">Required.</label>
   <input type="hidden" name="id">
   <input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="return editComment($(this).parent());" />
</form>
```

First off, I'd like to optimize these forms so that they are the best HTML5 semanticly. So What do you think, should everything within a form be wrapped in `fieldset` and why? Shouldn't `h1` be `legend` or `label`? And the error messages, is it legit that they are now a `label` or should they rather be `span`?

But my main question is: since these forms are so similar, I could do three things with it:

- keep the forms separate and make javascript hide one and show the other at the right time (as in the code above)
- combine the forms in one form, giving some tags `class="only_for_commenting"` and others `class="only_for_editing"` (as in the code below)
- combine the forms in one form, wrapping the tags in `fieldset`s according to when they should be shown (as in the code at the very bottom)

combined using classes:

```
<form>
   <h1 class="only_for_commenting">Comment</h1>
   <h1 class="only_for_editing" style="display:none;">Edit your comment</h1>
   <label>Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="50" maxlength="60" /></label>
   <label class="title_error error">Required.</label>
   <label>Author: <input type="text" name="author_name" size="25" maxlength="35" /></label>
   <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="8" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
   <label class="content_error error">Required.</label>
   <input class="only_for_editing" type="hidden" name="id">
   <input class="only_for_commenting" type="submit" value="Reageer" onclick="return addComment($(this).parent());" />
   <input class="only_for_editing" type="submit" value="Wijzig" onclick="return editComment($(this).parent());" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

combined using fieldsets: **Edit:** I've been conviced that this solution is the worst

```
<form>
   <fieldset class="only_for_commenting">
      <h1>Comment</h1>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="only_for_editing">
      <h1 style="display:none;">Edit your comment</h1>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="for_both">
      <label>Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="50" maxlength="60" /></label>
      <label class="title_error error">Required.</label>
      <label>Author: <input type="text" name="author_name" size="25" maxlength="35" /></label>
      <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="8" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
      <label class="content_error error">Required.</label>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="only_for_editing">
      <input type="hidden" name="id">
      <input type="submit" value="Wijzig" onclick="return editComment($(this).parent());" style="display:none;" />
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="only_for_commenting">
      <input type="submit" value="Reageer" onclick="return addComment($(this).parent());" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

So which option is the best semantically?

**Edit:** so I'm still thinking of three different solutions. I could have two separate forms (first block of code), or these two forms in different `fieldset` tags enclosed in one `form` tag, or I could have one combined form with classes for every input so javascript can hide one class and show the other (second block of code). In order to be able to choose between them, I'd like some advice. Which one of the three options is true:

- The comment and edit form are two totally different forms semantically
- The comment and edit form are different fieldsets of one same form
- The comment and edit form are in fact to be seen as one and the same form

Comment: Do you really need two different forms?  Let the javascript handle the form action, don't inline the onClick - moving the heading outside the form, and show the correct heading depending on the action.  The ID field can be present and left empty for new comments.

Comment: I've also been thinking about that but that would mean with every change I want to make I would have to edit the javascript code so much and I guess it's favorable to keep that very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Well semantics is always debatable, but i think what you could try is that wrap both the forms in different field sets as the purpose of both the forms are different and according to me that is the point of semantics. You could give both the forms different class names and switch accordingly.

And regarding the error message query you should use a label as if a screen reader is in place its more likely to detect the error than a non-label element.

But as i said semantics are always debatable, you could at the end choose what makes more sense to you.